Email template issue using handlebars js in nest js
I am trying to use handlebars js in my nest js project to send email. Email sending properly but in email body content not rendered properly. It creates responsive issue , styling issue .
in my template
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"  style="font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>My title</title> 
<style type="text/css">
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?    family=Anek+Bangla:wght@100..800&family=Noto+Serif+Bengali:wght@100..900&display=swap");
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
font-family: "Anek Bangla", sans-serif;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #3e3e3e;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {.template {padding: 2.5rem 1.5rem;} button {width: 100%;}}
</style>
</head>
<body>
............................ So on

How can I get actual view of my template in email . Thanks in advance


The reasons for emails not rendering properly in your Handlebars.js template are:

external CSS
fonts (which many email clients don't fully support)


use inline CSS for styling and rely on system fonts.
Try exploring MJML framework, which effectively addresses these compatibility and responsiveness issues.


Thanks but how may I convert my html template into MJML ?

No, it is not possible. there are no such tools. You need to manually convert html to mjml.
You can try using drag-and-drop tools such as easy-email or Grapejs to design the template and export it as MJML or HTML.
